# sprintf format specifier for numbers greater than UINT32

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to print sum of two `uint32_t` types into a buffer using `sprintf`. Their sum can potentially be larger than uint32_max, so I capture the result into int64_t. Here is a small snippet I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    char tmp[100] = {0};
    int64_t num = UINT32_MAX+2;
    sprintf(tmp, "%" PRId64, num);
    printf("A: %s\n", tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer for this is `A: 1` [gcc], which means the value overflowed. Expected value is `4294967295 + 2 = 4294967297`. Previous answers have suggested using the specifier `PRId64` but that doesn't seem to have helped. Can you point out my mistake in this snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the format, but the math!

```
int64_t num = UINT32_MAX + 2;
```

The participants to addition are both 32-bit values, and so is the result: modulo 2^32 yields a result of `1`.

If you add `LL` to the end of the constant, it makes one of the operands 64 bits, so the addition is don that way too.

```
int64_t num = UINT32_MAX + 2LL;
```

Comment: oh wow, thanks! how can I handle this in case of variables [the addition LL part]? For example a+b where both are uint32_max values?

Comment: Cast one of them to a 64-bit type?  `int64_t num = a + (int64_t)b;`  I want to caution you that one ought not just toss a cast in without really understanding the integral promotion rules, you have to know how signed and unsigned play together, and if you get it wrong you end up with unhappy truncation surprises such as the one that prompted you to visit Stack Overflow today :-)

Comment: To avoid a cast (good thing), simply include a wider 0. `0LL + a + b;`.  Trust the compiler to emit efficient code.

Comment: @chux now that’s a damn fine idea.